# Is it possible to use your own laravel package before registering it on Packagist?

Tags: laravel, packagist

I created a Laravel package (it is located in a private BitBucket repository) and I would like to test it in a new Laravel project if it works the way I want before registering it on Packagist. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: check the vcs repositories https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to add information where to look for your source code to composer.json. For example you could add your own private repository.

[How to add private repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories%20%20Adding%20private%20Repositories)

There are other possibilites, too. I suggest reading through the [corresponding composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

Comment: Regardless of linking to external source, you should add more info to your answer otherwise it will become useless as soon as your link stops working

Comment: Of course you are generally right... But the question is too broad in fact, as we know nothing about how and where his source code is located. So the only useful information I can give is, that it is possible and that this scenario is documentated at the composer site.